# Keras: Predict model within custom loss function

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use `some_model.predict(x)` within a custom loss function.

I found this custom loss function:

```
_EPSILON = K.epsilon()

def _loss_tensor(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, _EPSILON, 1.0-_EPSILON)
    out = -(y_true * K.log(y_pred) + (1.0 - y_true) * K.log(1.0 - y_pred))
    return K.mean(out, axis=-1)
```

But the problem is that `model.predict()` is expecting a numpy array.
So I looked for how to convert a tensor (`y_pred`) to a numpy array.
I found `tmp = K.tf.round(y_true)` but this returns a tensor.
I have also found: `x = K.eval(y_true)` which takes a Keras variable and returns a numpy array.
This produces the error: `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_78_target' with dtype float....`.
Some people suggested setting the learning phase to true. I did that, but it did not help.

What I just want to do:

```
def _loss_tensor(y_true, y_pred):
    y_tmp_true = first_decoder.predict(y_true)
    y_tmp_pred = first_decoder.predict(y_pred)

    return keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_tmp_true,y_tmp_pred)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This works:

```
sess = K.get_session()
with sess.as_default():
  tmp = K.tf.constant([1,2,3]).eval()
  print(tmp)
```

I also tried this now:

```
tmp = first_decoder(y_true)
```

This fails the assertion:

```
assert input_shape[-1]
```

Maybe someone knows how to resolve this?

**Update:**
I can now feed it through the model with:

```
y_t = first_decoder(K.reshape(y_true, (1,512)))
y_p = first_decoder(K.reshape(y_pred, (1,512)))
```

But when I try to return the binary cross entropy the shape is not right:

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 131072 values, but the requested shape has 
512
```

I figured out that 131072 was the product of my batch size and input size (256*512). I then adopted my code to reshape to (256,512) size. The first batch runs fine, but then I get another error that says that the passed size was (96,512).

**[SOLVED]Update:**
It works now:

```
def _loss_tensor(y_true, y_pred):
    num_ex = K.shape(y_true)[0]
    y_t = first_decoder(K.reshape(y_true, (num_ex,512)))
    y_p = first_decoder(K.reshape(y_pred, (num_ex,512)))

    return keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_t,y_p)
```